# Is this the correct way to add permissions to the androidmanifest in React Native?

Tags: react-native, mobile, geolocation, android-manifest

I am trying to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION to get real time location from the device. I am adding those permissions in the app.json file. Am I doing it the right way?
[image: app.json]

Comment: Are you using expo?